# wkhtmltopdf не выводит шапку страницы используя header-html

Tags: php, html, ubuntu

Версия wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Использую скрипт

```
$tmp1=time();
$fenom = $modx->getService("pdoTools");
$llg = $fenom->getChunk("anketa.tpl", $info);
$f=fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/tmp/'.$tmp1.'.html','w');
fputs($f, $llg);
fclose($f);

$cd = "cd ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/tmp';
exec($cd);
$command = "wkhtmltopdf --margin-top 35mm --margin-bottom 27mm --margin-left 10mm --margin-right 10mm --header-html ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/tmp/pdf_header.html ' .$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/tmp/'.$tmp1.'.html'." ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/tmp/'."$tmp1.pdf";;
exec($command);
```

pdf_header.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      </head>
      <body>
       Шапка
      </body>
     </html>
```

Контент

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
       </head>
       <body>
         Контент
       </body>
     </html>
```

**Обновление**

Решение было установка таким образом
https://gist.github.com/faniska/37f896d5e9de5fee925925d7caf3cb9e

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста подробностей к вопросу, формируется ли ваш временный файл из modx,, правильно ли формируется команда $command может там пути неправильные или еще-что, есть ли записи в лог файлах (самого modx и системных), что получается, если из командной строки выполнить получаемую в $command

Comment: Тут: `'/tmp/pdf_header.html'. ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` точно ничего не пропущено? может там `." ".` должно стоять? и в конце две точки с запятой, одной вполне хватает

Comment: Да код выполняется из modx. Ошибок в путях нет это моя помарка должно быть так '/tmp/pdf_header.html '.$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. По результату я вижу только контент без шапки. Она как будто игнорируется.

Comment: Все так попробуйте вывести получаемую $command в логи или еще куда, проверьте ее (наличие файлов и пр.), и попробуйте ее выполнить если есть доступ по ssh или другим способом, можно скачать оба файла header и tmp1 к себе и попробовать сформировать pdf у себя, у вас например в приведенных файлах pdf_header.html не закрыт тег html может еще какие ошибки есть, надо смотреть что подаете на вход wkhtmltopdf и что получается

Comment: Запустил программу через ssh и увидел следующее "The switch --header-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.Loading page (1/2) Printing pages (2/2) QPainter::begin(): Returned false".
Поискал в интернете информацию по этому поводу и помогла такая переустановка https://gist.github.com/faniska/37f896d5e9de5fee925925d7caf3cb9e.
Спасибо за помощь! Я уже начал терять надежду)